# find $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \|T_n x\| $?

Tags: functional-analysis

let $T_n= S^n$ , where  the operators  $S\colon l^2 \to l^2$  is  defined  by  $(x_1, x_2, x_3 ,\dots)\to (x_3, x_4, x_5 ,\dots) $.
find $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \|T_n x\| $?

**My attempt** : Given $T_n= S^n $

$S^n=( x_{2n+1} , x_{2n+2} ,\dots)$ and   $(x_n)_j= \begin{cases} 1  \ \text{if } j= 2n+1 \\ 0 \ \text{if } \ j \neq   2n-1 \end{cases}$

since  $S$  equip with $l^2$  norm  so $\|T_n x\| _2=1 \implies  \lim_{n\to \infty} \|T_n x\| =1$

Comment: What do you mean by $(x_n)_j$? The $j$th coordinate of a real (complex?) number $x_n$? What if $j$ is neither $2n+1$ nor $2n-1$?

Comment: Clearly your answer is wrong. $S^n (1,0,0, \dots,)= (0,0, \dots)$.

Comment: @Gary im talking about real

Comment: Your answer should depend on $x$. E.g. it should double if you replace $x$ with $2x$. Write out what $T^nx \in \ell^2$ is and then think about the norm of this element in $\ell^2$.

Comment: @jasmine I think you missed the main point of my question. What do you mean by $(x_n)_j$? The $x_n$ is a real number, what is the $j$th coordinate of a real number? You say that this is $1$ if $j=2n+1$ and $0$ if $j=2n-1$. What if $j=2n$ for example?

Comment: okk  @Gary  i think  if $j= 2n $then  $x_n$ may be $0$ or $1$,...My bad thinking     actually  i was just  construct $(x_n)_j$ to make answer $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_n\|S^n (x_1, x_2, \dots)\|^2 = \lim_n \|(x_{2n+1}, x_{2n+2}, \dots)\|^2= \lim_n \sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty |x_k|^2= 0$$
since the series $\sum_k |x_k|^2 < \infty$.